# Javascript variable lifecycle, will the variable be copied when it is returned?

Tags: javascript, function

It is hard to describe the situation without code.
My modification made some answers irrelevant. I past the original code here and simplified version below:

```
function Entity(){
  var value = {};

  return {
    'value': value
  };
}

var e1 = Entity();
var e2 = Entity();
alert(e1.value === e2.value);
```

I thought it should return true. But in fact, it returns false. Is 'value' copied when it is returned from the function Entity?

**update**
I think I know the reason now. each time Entity function is called the expression "var value={};" will generate a new Object. Thanks.

Comment: `{0, 1}` doesn't equal `{0, 1}`... same concept

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: I know that {0,1} doesn't equal to {0,1}. My question is why e1.value and e2.value (in the simplified version) are not referencing to the same instance in the function.

Comment: Because the reference is recreated in each scope you create (i.e., a new "`value`" each time). Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2hx6/): both `b` and `c` contain a reference to the original `a`. However, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2hx6/1/), both are referring to a different "`a`"

Comment: Also - do you mind getting rid of the original version in your code above? It's just confusing to readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value is not copied when its returned, but a new Object is created whenever you run the Entity function.

You can observe the "new Object" creation with simple code like

```
console.log({} === {}) //should give false

var a = {};
console.log(a === a); //should give true
```

And you can check that things don't get copyed on return by assigning to more variables when running your function

```
var a,b,c;

function Entity(){
   var value = {};
   a = value;
   b = value;
   return value;
}

c = Entity();

console.log(a==b, a==c, b==c); //should all give true
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that in general distinct Objects are never equal (in strict or abstract comparison), and that only numbers, strings and booleans can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

`[elements...]` syntax creates a new array.
In javascript, `===` operator compares arrays by reference (not by contents), so the result is `false`

Comment: Do you mind delete your answer? Because after I revised the question, it is not applicable now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is currently creating a new object each time it is getting called.

Keeping the **same interface as in your example**, to share the **same array**, you could do the following ->

```
Entity = (function () {
    //this variable is accessible only in the scope of this function
    var messageBoxes = ['hello'];

    //we return a function that return an object that will make the private messageBoxes variable accessible through it's messageBoxes property.
    return function () {
        return { messageBoxes: messageBoxes };
    };
})(); //note that this function will be self-executing


alert(Entity().messageBoxes === Entity().messageBoxes);
```

However, you would not be gaining anything here since you would be making the private `messageBoxes` variable publicly accessible directly.